# parse a json object with a variable as a name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, pointers

I'm trying to use nodejs to find a JSON object named the same as a variable's value. I'm trying

```
var temp = thing.name;
var nameVal = vals.temp;
console.log(nameVal);`
```

but when printed, nameVal is undefined.

thing looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "workout"
}
```

and vals looks like:

```
{
    "workout": true
}
```

temp is correct

Comment: use bracket notation -> `var nameVal = vals[temp];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of point notation, use bracket notation.
Try this: `vals[temp]` or even `vals[thing.name]`